# Returning filter on the same template

Tags: django, filter, django-template-filters

I have a special queryset in my views.py
I wanted to return the products in short supply in the same ListView mentioned below.
Recalling that initial it returns all records.
When I clicked on the link 'products in short supply' give yes it would filter the page.

I ask:

1. how to keep the two views to normal and the filter in the same ListView below?
2. How to complete the link below?

`views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView, TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from django.db.models import F
from .models import Customer, Brand, Product, Sale, SaleDetail


class ProductList(ListView):
    template_name = 'product_list.html'
    model = Product
    context_object = 'product_list'
    paginate_by = 100


    def get_stock_down(self):
        s = Product.objects.filter(stoq__lt=F('stoq_min'))
        var_get_filter = self.request.GET.get('filter_link')
        return s
```

`product_list.html`:

```
<p name="filter_link" class="pull-right"><a href="">Produtos em baixo estoque</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you nearly have it.

Instead of adding a new method to the view I think you should override `get_queryset`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    s = Product.objects.all()
    if self.request.GET.get('filter_link', False):
        s = s.filter(stoq__lt=F('stoq_min'))
    return s
```

and

```
<p name="filter_link" class="pull-right"><a href="?filter_link=1">Produtos em baixo estoque</a></p>
```